# Openweather API

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, openweathermap

I am making app for the first time using open weather api,how can i get city name in the url, using append .
[enter link description here][1]

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Westervile,oh,us&APPID=2fa22bb3ea6b43ae727b045b5e49e5f3"];

NSData*data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *citiesNamesResponse = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
totalCities=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSDictionary *results = [citiesNamesResponse  JSONValue] ;
NSMutableString *mu = [NSMutableString stringWithString:urlString];
[mu insertString:@"name" atIndex:[mu length] - 39];
```

I am trying to set name(which is city name ) to get on searchbar.

Comment: Show the image here

Comment: `append . [enter link description here][1]` ??

Comment: your can do via parse the response the set as City name to searchbar.

Comment: yes it works, thx